# Encrypted Video Playback Adobe AIR (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

Suppose you have an encrypted video file and the associated AES key.  Is it possible to play that video in a flex AIR application without saving the decrypted version of the file?  How?

Answer (score 1):

If you do go the DRM route, I believe the Flash Media server supports all this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The easiest way would be to use flash access or flash media server as others have suggested.

The hard way is to create everything yourself using NetStream and the appendBytes method. With appendBytes the data for the video can come from anywhere in any form and it is up to you to put it into the correct form to be played. 
Take a look at this question on appendBytes:
[In AS3 while using NetStream for video playback how do I seek when I use appendBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825103/in-as3-while-using-netstream-for-video-playback-how-do-i-seek-when-i-use-appendb/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are protecting content, being adobe, I suspect that AIR will have some form of **DRM** api that you can use.

[This](http://www.google.com/search?q=Adobe+AIR+DRM) returns alot of data about protecting videos in Flash/AIR and other adobe products.