# AS3 NetStream AppendBytes Seek issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ffmpeg, air, netstream

I'm having trouble with NetStream in AS3. The project I am working on allows users to browse a video (locally) and play it back. The issue I am having is that `netStream.seek(0);` from what I can tell it doesn't do anything, although I get inside a NetStatusEvent function and `NetStream.Seek.Notify` is triggered. I'm using NativeProcess and the following function is this makes any difference.

```
public function ProgressEventOutputHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    videoByteArray = new ByteArray();
    nativeProcess.standardOutput.readBytes(videoByteArray, 0, nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
    netStream.appendBytes(videoByteArray);
}
```

Am I missing something here? I am pausing netStream before using `netStream.seek(0);`.

**EDIT:**

In an attempt to fix this issue I followed the instructions by VC.One I've done the following:

- Moved `videoByteArray = new ByteArray();` to my init function and also created `tempVideoByteArray = new ByteArray();` in this function.
- Update my ProgressEventOutputHandler function so that it no longer created a new ByteArray for videoByteArray and changed this line -  `nativeProcess.standardOutput.readBytes(videoByteArray, videoByteArray.length, nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);`

I have changed nothing else and now the video will not load. If I allow a new ByteArray to be created inside the ProgressEventOutputHandler function the video does load again.

Comment: That code setup isn't flexible for seeking. You should make `videoStream` outside of the function **once only** and then fill it up on each progress event (it will fire many times as data comes through from FFMPEG, here its like you destroy the last data and make a new one. Okay but imagine the final progressEvent gave final 10 secs of a 5 min video, now how can you seek to 2 minutes when your (new) bytes only hold final 10 secs? If instead you filled up one byteArray only it would have all bytes and you can seek within them.

Comment: You need two byte arrays really. Bytes One holds the full bytes and will grow as they come in. Something like `xxxx.readBytes(videoStream, videoStream.length, xxxx.bytesAvailable);` here xxxx is just to shorten code but you know what I mean. Bytes Two is a "temp" buffer that you fill with specific frame bytes and append. Bytes Two can be cleared for re-use with example `temp_BA.clear();` so no need for using `= new..` since that actually adds multiple bytearrays into memory all called the same name (compiler just sees them as 1000 unique reference ID's).

Comment: Anyways my point was... seeking with `appendBytes` is self-controlled. You decide which bytes you feed in so you pick the correct bytes range from `videoStream` and copy to `temp_BA` whereby you then append temp_BA. Wanna seek elsewhere? clear temp_BA and fill with a grab from videoStream again. You use two so that the main one videoStream is left untouched to avoid issues with "adjusting it" while also feeding it etc. I'll elaborate later.. To seek find the bytes of a keyframe and append that

Comment: Updated question to include comments by VC.One

Comment: Still searching for an answer to this issue if anyone has any more ideas. Not really tried much else as the NetStream documentation isn't too helpful and hit a brick wall now.

Comment: @AntBirch Did you tried [`NetStream.appendBytesAction()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytesAction()) ? Also, take a look on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3825103/2256820).

Comment: The problem may be that `NetStream.seek(0)` seeks to the nearest key frame  rather than the specific frame at 0 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Version :**

Try the code I pasted here: [Github Snippet](https://gist.github.com/Valerio-Charles-VC1/657054b773dba9ba1cbc) link

**Long version :**

***this one's kinda long but hope it helps once and for all***... Don't worry about the brick wall thing, walls are made to be smashed. To keep you inspired, check out some in-house demos from the VC:One labs using `appendBytes` :

- **[MP4 Seeking Experiment](http://vcone.co.uk/labs/video/AS3_AB_seek_v01.html)** : research for `appendBytes` frame data access and time/seek handling. Real-time frame bytes convert from MP4 to FLV format using only AS3 code.
- **[Speed Adjust of Audio & Video](http://vcone.co.uk/labs/video/AS3_AB_speed_v01.html)** : for real-time MP3 audio in video separation & effecting experiment. Requires MP4/FLV  file with MP3 data in the audio track.
- **[Synchronised Video Frames](http://vcone.co.uk/labs/video/AS3_AB_sync_v01.html)** : for multiple videos displaying by the same frame number.

PS: I'll be using `URLStream` method as that's a more useful answer to those loading local or online files. You could change from `urlstream.progressEvent` to your usual  `nativeProcess.progressEvent`.
I know FFMPEG but only used AIR for making Android apps. So for this AIR/FFMPEG connection you know more than me.

Also this answer assumes you're using **FLV with MPEG H.264 video & MP3 or AAC audio**.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 FLV_with_MP3.flv`

This assumption matters because it affects what kind of bytes we look for.
In the case of the above FLV with a H.264 video and AAC or MP3 audio we can expect the following (when seeking) :

- Since this is MPEG the first video tag will hold **AVC Decoder Config** bytes and the first audio tag holds the **Audio Specific Config** bytes. This data is not actual media frames but simply packaged like an audio/video tag. These are needed for MPEG playback. The same bytes can be found in the `STSD` metadata entry (`MOOV` atom) inside an MP4 container. Now the next found video tag will (or should) be the video's actual first frame.
- **Video keyframe** : begins **0x09** and next 11th byte is **0x17** & 12th byte is **0x01**
- **Audio TAG AAC** : begins **0x08** and next 11th byte is **0xAF** & 12th byte is **0x01**
- **Audio TAG MP3** : begins **0x08** and next 11th byte is **0x2F** & 12th byte is **0xFF**

## 1) Bytes copying and checking values :

You are looking for bytes that represent a video "tag". Apart from the Metadata tag, you can now expect "tag" to mean a container of an audio or video frame. There are two ways to get tag bytes into your "temporary byte array" (we'll name it as `temp_BA` ).

- `ReadBytes` (slow) : extracts the individual byte values within a start/end range in `source_BA`
- `WriteBytes` (fast) : instant duplication of a start/end range of bytes from `source_BA`

**[Readbytes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readBytes()) explained** : *tells Source to read its bytes **into Target**. Source will read forwards up to the length from its current offset (position). **Go to correct Source position before reading onwards**...* 
`source_BA.readBytes( into Target_BA, Pos within Target_BA, length of bytes required );`
*After the above line executes, Source position will now **have moved forward** to account for the new length travelled. (formula : Source new Pos = previousPos + BytesLengthRequired).*

**[Writebytes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeBytes()) explained** : *tells Target to duplicate a range of bytes **from Source**. Is fast since copying from already-known information (from Source). **Target writes onwards from its current position**...*  
`target_BA.writeBytes( from source_BA, Pos within source_BA, length of bytes required );`
*After the above line executes, note that both Source and Target **positions are unchanged**.*

Use above methods to get required tag bytes into `temp_BA` from a specific `source_BA.position = x`.

To check any byte (its value), use the methods below to update some variable of `int` type:

- Read a [one-byte value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readByte())  : use `my_Integer = source_BA.readByte();`
- Read a [two-byte value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readUnsignedShort())  : use `my_Integer = source_BA.readUnsignedShort();`
- Read a [four-byte value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readUnsignedInt()) : use `my_Integer = source_BA.readUnsignedInt();`
- variable `Number` for [eight-byte value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readDouble()) : use `my_Number = source_BA.readDouble();`

**note** : Don't confuse `.readByte();` which extracts a numerical value (of byte) with the similar sounding `.readBytes()` which copies a chunk of bytes to another byte array.

## 2) Finding A Video KeyFrame (or I-frame) :

[ illustration image of Video TAG with Keyframe H264/AAC ]

**To find a video keyframe**

- From a starting offset, use a `while` loop to now travel [forward] through the bytes searching each byte for a [one-byte value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readByte()) of "**9**" ( hex: `0x09`), when found we check further ahead bytes to confirm that indeed it's a true keyframe and not just a random occurence of "9".
- In the case of H.264 video codec, at the correct "**9**" byte position (xPos) we expect the **11th & 12th bytes ahead always to be** "**17**" and "**01**" respectively.
- `If` that is `== true` then we check the three **Tag Size** bytes and add **15** to this integer for the total length of bytes expected to be written from Source into Target ( `temp_BA`). We have added **15** to account for the 11 bytes *before* and also the 4 bytes *after* expected TAG DATA. These 4 bytes at tag ending are "Previous Tag Size" and this amount actually includes the 11 front bytes but not counting these end 4 bytes themselves.
- We tell `temp_BA` to **write bytes** of *Source* (your `videoByteArray`) **starting from** pos of "**9**" byte (xPos)  for a **length of** "Tag Size" + 15. You have now extracted an MPEG keyframe. 
  ***example*** : `temp_BA.writeBytes( videoByteArray, int (xPos), int (TAG_size) );`
- This `temp_BA` with tag of a Keyframe can now be appended using: 
  ***example*** : `netStream.appendBytes( temp_BA ); //displays a single frame`

**note** : For reading 3 bytes of Tag Size I will show a custom converting `bytes_toInt()` function (since processors read either 1, 2 or 4 bytes at once for integers, reading 3 bytes here is an akward request).

**Searching tip** : Tags always follow each other in a trail. We can seek faster by also checking if bytes are for a non-keyframe (P frame) video tag or even some audio tag. If so then we check that particular `tag size` and now increment our `xPos` to jump this new length. This way we can skip by whole tag sizes not just by single bytes. Stopping only when we have a keyframe tag.

## 3) Playback From A Video KeyFrame :

When you think about it, play is simply like an auto-seek going on a frame by frame basis. Where the expected speed of getting each next frame is defined by the video's encoded framerate.

So your **playback function** can simply be a `Timer` that gets X-amount of video tags (frames) every second (or 1000 milisecs). You do that as example `my_Timer = new Timer ( video_FPS )`. When the timer runs and reaches each FPS slice of a second it will run the `append_PLAY();` function which in turn runs a `get_frame_Tag();` function.

- `NS.seek(0)` : Puts NetStream into "seek mode". (the number doesn't matter but must exist in the command). Any "ahead frames" buffer is cleared and they'll be no (image) frame updates until..
- **`RESET_SEEK`** : Ends the "seek mode" and now allows image updates. The first tag you append after using the `RESET_SEEK` command must be a tag with a video keyframe. (for audio-only this can be any tag since technically all audio tags are audio keyframes)
- **`END_SEQUENCE`** : (for MPEG H.264) Plays out any remaining "ahead frames" (drains the buffer). Once drained you can now append any type of video tag. Remember H.264 expects forward-moving timestamps, If you see f**ked up pixels then your next tag timestamp is wrong (too high or too low). If you appending just one frame (poster image?) you could use `END_SEQUEMCE` to drain the buffer and display that one frame (without waiting for buffer to fill up to x-amount of frames first)...

The **play function** acts as a middle-man function to manage things without cluttering the **get frame** function with `If` statements etc. Managing things means for example checking that there are enough bytes downloaded to even begin getting a frame according to Tag Size.

## 4) Source Code For A Working Example :

Code is too long.. see this [link](https://gist.github.com/Valerio-Charles-VC1/657054b773dba9ba1cbc) below:
https://gist.github.com/Valerio-Charles-VC1/657054b773dba9ba1cbc

Hope it helps. VC

Comment: Hi Ant, if you see this... this post is correct (thanks for accepting) but I reckon it needs streamlining a bit, eh? Also will update links to the demos later on. Had to remove them to protect the code but they'll be up when I figure out something in future (ie: when this comment will be deleted)