# AS3 size of data types for byte arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I have a byte array and I want to rad the first 10 bytes and store as a string, the next 138 bytes are junk, then the next 4 bytes should be a number. I have some code but it's not working as I would expect, I get a number I was not expecting.

```
var byteData:ByteArray;
var store:ByteArray;
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("file.bin");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.load(url);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);

function loaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
    byteData = new ByteArray();
    store = new ByteArray();
    byteData.position = 0;
    byteData.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    store.position = 0;
    store.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    name_string = loader.data.readMultiByte(10,"iso-8859-01");
    loader.data.readBytes(byteData,loader.data.position,138);
    loader.data.readBytes(store,loader.data.position,4);
    trace(store);
}
```

or if I read an int: trace(loader.data.readInt()); I still get the wrong value.

sorry, I'm not good with bytearrays.

Is an int 4x bytes for as3 or should it be a short?

Where can I find the byte size of data types? Thanks.

Comment: What is that loader type you are using?

Comment: Yes, 4 bytes for an int http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7fff.html

Comment: Thanks 4 bytes. Loader info added in edit.... Any ideas why I get the wrong int? Am I using readbytes correctly? –

Comment: how is this related to this previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775001/as3-binary-file-with-unknown-data-type

Comment: @iain Just a guess, but I'm not sure if you need to set the offset. Try setting the second paramter to zero for both calls to `readBytes()`?

Comment: Yeah thanks,  a.readbytes(b) offset does an offset into b not into a.

Comment: Is the provided answer not working for you? If it was useful please up-vote or else give feedback. thanks. (ps: fixed the `.position = 10` hiccup, forgot we read first byte at `pos=0` so end up at `pos=9` with the 10th byte).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you check this for reference : **[AS3 ByteArray API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html)**

Also note that in AS3 reading byte values automatically moves the pointer's position. It has to step over the byte slots to know their values so to read an Integer it will move ahead 4 bytes from whatever position you had before running something like : `myInt = myBytes.readUnsignedInt();`

Use `readBytes` and `writeBytes` only for copying bytes between ByteArrays.
 To get actual byte values use: (as quoted from **[this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182580/as3-netstream-appendbytes-seek-issue/33707293#33707293)**)

> To check any byte (its value), use the methods below to update some
>   variable of `int` type:
>
> - Read a [one-byte value]  : use `my_Integer = source_BA.readByte();`
> - Read a [two-byte value]  : use `my_Integer = source_BA.readUnsignedShort();`
> - Read a [four-byte value] : use `my_Integer = source_BA.readUnsignedInt();`
> - variable `Number` for [eight-byte value] : use `my_Number = source_BA.readDouble();`

Anyways try this code below in your function...

```
function loaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
    byteData = new ByteArray();
    store = new ByteArray();

    //# set both vars to same values at once by chaining
    byteData.position = store.position = 0; 
    byteData.endian = store.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;

    //# put bytes into byteData
    byteData = URLLoader(e.target).data as ByteArray;
    //byteData = ByteArray(loader.data); //shorter but untested

    //# 1) Get 10 character string
    name_string = byteData.readUTFBytes( 10 );

    //# 2) Skip the +138 bytes
    byteData.position = 9; //if paranoid just manually set pointer to pos 9 (for 10th byte)
    byteData.position += 138; //increment forward by Plus 138 bytes from current pos 

    //# 3)  Extract (4 byte) Integer from pointer offset 148
    var my_Number : int = byteData.readUnsignedInt(); //moves pointer Plus 4 bytes after reading

    trace( "my_Number from bytes is : " + my_Number );
}
```